# CSS Float adding to the height of button

Tags: html, css

OK something strange is going on here, i am using a class for 2 buttons that share styles. But when i apply a float right to one of the buttons it makes it bigger 26px vs 30px in my real world example.

It is only changing by 1px in this http://jsfiddle.net/Mag2D/ but it is still different.

I have a screen grab of inspect elements that show the 26 vs 30 here https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfTqu.jpg

This is the CSS that is being used...

```
    .orderButton {
    position: relative;
    -moz-borderradius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #004282;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    }
    .right{float:right;}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: something should be overriding it to know what it is more code would be needed for me its 144pxX29px and 144pxX30px

Comment: I've found that adding `padding` to inline elements is generally a bad idea because of the inconsistent (and undesireable behaviour). If you have an inline element that you want to assign padding/heights/widths to, make it easy on yourself and set it to `display: inline-block` (which also solves your problem)

Comment: Float them both, one right and one left. They end up perfect when they are both floated. The reasoning is... <a> are not block level elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that when you float an inline element, it then becomes an `inline-block` element, which changes the way padding/width/height/margin properties are painted.

Whenever you have an inline element (e.g. `span`, `a`, etc) that you want to add padding to, make sure you set it to `display: inline-block`. It will display much more consistently cross-browser and, most likely, will be more likely to display the way you intended it to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation on why and not just telling me to float the other one left, because that is not what i want!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here: 1) anchors are not block level elements. 2) when you float non-block level elements, they get turned into an inline-block level element and thus their model is changed.

If you set both to be floated by adding a "left" class to the left button and adding the float, they come out perfect.

**HTML :**

```
 <a class="orderButton left">Place Order</a>

 <a class="orderButton right">Place Order</a>
```

**CSS :**

```
.orderButton {
       position: relative;
       -moz-borderradius: 4px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       border-radius: 4px;
       background-color: #004282;
       color: #fff;
       padding: 5px 35px;
}
.right{float:right;}
.left{float:left;}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain your answer instead of expecting us to  do a mental diff.

Comment: Yeah an exmplanation would have been helpful because i dont want the other button to be floated right. It was just in my fiddle that way because it would be impossible to show my entire page.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1:**

Add this in the CSS:

```
.left{float:left;}
```

And add `left` class to the `a` tag

```
<a class="orderButton left">Place Order</a>
```

**Solution #2:**

In `.orderButton`, add:

```
display:inline-block;
```

When you `float` an element, it automatically becomes a block box. This box can then be shifted to the left or right on the current line but it also changes its `margin`, `padding` etc.

**[Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/Mag2D/1/)** - With `float` on both `a` tags

**[Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/Mag2D/3/)** - With `inline-block;` on the `button` class instead